# Black screen after start up

Tags: screen

I recently installed ubuntu on my laptop (hp denvy dv6) and last night in the middle of using my computer, it powered off. Whenever I try to turn on my computer, I can hear the fans turn on, but the display doesn't turn on.

Things I've tried:
Plug laptop into another display

Boot ubuntu from a flashdrive

Pressing shift to get to GRUB doesn't work

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: seems something is wrong with your laptop's BIOS

Comment: Can you access the BIOS?

Comment: I can't access the BIOS